# How do I set the increment in a graph in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm generating and drawing a graph in matplotlib in python, and I can't figure out how to stop the y axis representing itself in terms of multiples of `e`. The values on the y axis that I'm getting are between 0.01 and 0.05, with a +2.288e1 at the top of the axis. These do actually map to "sensible" values around 20. How do I force matplotlib to not use this notation?

```
def plotTime(a, aName, b, bName, graphTitle):
    print a
    print b
    if max(a) >= max(b):
        plt.axhline(max(a), color='r')
    else:
        plt.axhline(max(b), color='r')

    if max(a) >= max(b):
        plt.axhline(max(a), color='r')
    else:
        plt.axhline(max(b), color='r')

    a, = plt.plot(a)
    b, = plt.plot(b)
    plt.legend([a, b], [aName, bName])
    plt.suptitle(graphTitle, fontsize=20)
    plt.ylabel('Time (min)')
    plt.xlabel('xth file created')
    plt.show()
    return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tweak by speifying the limit of axis using [ticklabel_format](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ticklabel_format):

```
plt.ticklabel_format(axis='y', style='plain', scilimits=(-2,2))
```

You can also try another way to solve it by adding:

```
plt.gca().get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)

plt.gca().get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
```

Try also to make the representation in vertical way to avoid the overlapping text (but it's still a suggestion).

```
   plt.yticks(rotation='vertical')
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying that `'module' object has no attribute 'ticklabel_format'`, don't suppose you'd happen to know how to fix that?

Comment: @Yann: Did you try the other way: plt.gca().get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)

Comment: How do you import matplotlib ? It should be this way: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt